# Installing Pandas using Pip on Windows 8.1 with Python 3.4

Tags: python, pandas, pip, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to install Pandas on my machine using Pip after downloading the necessary .whl file off of Pandas website. I'm running into the problem that Visual C++ 10.0 is required and that it was unable to find the vcvarsall.bat file(I think for Numpy and Pandas). I know that Python 3.4 is built on the vs100 compiler of Microsoft's and that most people's solution is to install visual studio 2010 express to get it (Although it seems Microsoft has moved on to visual studio 2012 & 2013 express and I can't find the 2010 express edition). However, I already have the full Visual studio 2013 installed with the vs120 path already included. Whenever I try to install Visual Studio Express 2012 it always asks me to uninstall 2013 before proceeding. I would rather not have to do this to install Pandas so my question is: Can I redirect vs100 to point to vs120 or would this cause problems? I've read elsewhere that redirecting the compiler isn't a proper fix but those were for Python 2.* and I don't see any other way around this problem. Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not an answer but another solution which is to download Anaconda, which comes with Pandas installed and many other Scientific packages. I highly recommend it because pandas is hard to install manually. Anaconda is a like installing new Python, you have to change your environmental Variables as well.